# php многомерный массив, объединить массивы внутри массива

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет!
Есть один массив внутри которого около 20 массивов, такого вида:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sergei 
            [surname] => Kovalev
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Alexander 
            [surname] => Usik
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Genadii 
            [surname] => Golovkin
        )
)
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Anatolii 
            [surname] => Lomachenko
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Murat 
            [surname] => Gasiev
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Alexander 
            [surname] => Povetkin
        )
)
Array
(
     ...
)
```

Как получить массив такого вида:

```
   [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sergei 
            [surname] => Kovalev
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Alexander 
            [surname] => Usik
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Genadii 
            [surname] => Golovkin
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Anatolii 
            [surname] => Lomachenko
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Murat 
            [surname] => Gasiev
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Alexander 
            [surname] => Povetkin
        )
    [n] => Array
       (
            ...
       )
```

то есть объединить массивы внутри массива

Comment: `array_merge()`?

Comment: если быть точнее, то `array_merge(...$arr)`

Comment: внутри массива 21 массив, может быть ещё больше, как их обьединить все?

Comment: хотите циклом пройдитесь, хотите колбэк функцию

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data=array('0'=>array('2' => array(
            'name' => 'Sergei', 
            'surname' => 'Kovalev'
        ),

    '3' => array
        (
            'name' => 'Alexander', 
            'surname' => 'Usik'
        ),

    '4' => array
        (
            'name' => 'Genadii',
            'surname' => 'Golovkin'
        )
),
'1'=>array
(
    '2' => array
        (
            'name' => 'Anatolii', 
            'surname' => 'Lomachenko'
        ),

    '3' => array
        (
            'name' => 'Murat', 
            'surname' => 'Gasiev'
        ),

    '4' => array
        (
            'name' => 'Alexander', 
            'surname' => 'Povetkin'
        )
));


foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    # code...
foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
    # code...

$newmass[]=$value1;

}


}

print_r($newmass);
?>
```

Comment: у меня массив другого вида: $data = array(array()array()array())

Comment: а у меня какой в ответе тогда?

Comment: у вас array('0'=>array(),'1'=>array(),'2'=>array()), у меня array(array('0'=>...)array('0'=>...)array('0'=>...))

Comment: распечатай массив и закинь сюда вначале var_dump($arr); http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com

Comment: это всё распечатка одного массива, удалил в нем лишнее что бы читабельный был;  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f5d552eee8b6ae68c4e72e449707290ead3bf141

Comment: Такое ощущение что array(50) в цикле выводится

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e4d7c705407c4943b5d4a9dadb73e8409c9cf5f4   за место $mega свой поставь массив

Comment: спасибо большое, очень помогли, и правда цикл был

Answer (score -1):

```
$merged_array = [];
foreach ($parent_array as $arr) {
    $merged_array = array_merge($merged_array, $arr);
}
```